# Error: Container is not defined at gvjs_dp GeoChart in Angular

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="geochart" #geochart> </div>
```

Here is my TS code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','geochart'], mapsApiKey: 'XXXXmyAPIKEYXXXX'});

this.http.post(url,data,{responseType: 'text'})
 .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.geoChartArray = JSON.parse(data).data;
      this.drawGeoChart();
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}


drawGeoChart() {
   var geo_1_options = { is3D: true };   
   var geo_1_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.geoChartArray);
   var domElement = document.getElementById('geochart');
   var geo_1_chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(domElement);
   geo_1_chart.draw(geo_1_data, geo_1_options);
}
```

Sometimes the GeoChart loads and sometimes I get this error. I'm unable to figure out what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: @WhiteHat I have updated my TS file. Could you please check it.

Comment: @Anirudh What error are you getting?

Comment: @TeunvanderWijst Error: Container is not defined at gvjs_dp GeoChart

Answer (score 1):

Did you try moving your code to ngAfterViewInit? And also not using DOM API directly:

```js
@ViewChild('geochart') geochartEl: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.http...subscribe(() => {

  })
}

draw(...)  {
  const domElement = this.geochartEl.nativeElement;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback();`, based on looking at the Fiddle provided in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).

Try like this:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['geochart'],
  'mapsApiKey': 'XXXXmyAPIKEYXXXX'
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGeoChart);

this.http.post(url,data,{responseType: 'text'})
 .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.geoChartArray = JSON.parse(data).data;
      this.drawGeoChart();
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

drawGeoChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

  var options = {};

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```